# horizontal and vertical projection of an image

Tags: matlab

I am doing a project on image forgery detection in MatLab software. But I am new to both image processing and matlab.

Now **I  have to calculate horizontal and vertical projection of an image**. How to do it in matlab?

I have used

```
ver=imfilter(edge1,[1 0 -1])
```

and

```
hor=imfilter(edge1,[1 0 -1]')
```

where `edge1` is an edge image.

But i am not sure if it is right or not. Edge detection algorithm is based on the standard deviation. I have not used built in edge detection function. I have implemented standard deviation based edge detection.Can anybody help me on this . I need to know this very immediately. Thanks. Expecting your answers........

Answer (score 3):

What is image projection? I think using and edge detector is NOT correct.

If I remember correctly image project is an "histogram over horizontal or vertical way of grayscale level".

If you need a projection of the edges you developed the first step.

Then, I think you have to sum over rows or columns the grayscale of image.

```
sum(image,1)

sum(image,2)
```

here the projection of my photo (apologize fro my futility :)

[image: gv projection]

Comment: thank you for the answer. But output of the horizontal and vertical projection do not look like what you have shown. I will upload the algorithm as a separate question . Can i please have my problem get cleared?