# Finding the leftmost and the rightmost cell that is True in a 2d-list of booleans (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d-array (28 x 28) that has boolean values.

```
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
         True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       ...
```

This represents an image of a digit. In order to stretch this image so that the horizontal and vertical range of ink pixels runs the full horizontal/vertical range of the box.

Below are the steps that I am trying to take:

```
1. Find the leftmost (x_min) and the rightmost (x_max) pixels that have ink (after thresholding). 
2. Find the topmost (y_min) and bottom-most (y_max) pixels similarly. 
3. Find the centerpoint (x,y) by taking the mean of x_min and x_max and y_min and y_max respectively. 
4. Now, the 20x20 bounding is defined as img[y_center-10 : y_center + 10, x_center-10:x_center+10]
```

I tried to do `Step 1` in a naive way, just iterating all pixels, but I know that is not the best way. What is the best way to find the left and rightmost pixel that is `True`?

Comment: That's the same as this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54286937/2836621

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function index, which returns the first index of the value you search for:

e.g.

```
array = ([False, False, True, True, False])
print(array.index(True))
```

Returns

```
2
```

You can reverse the array to find the last one, by adding:

```
array.reverse();
print(array.index(True))
```

Which returns

```
1
```

However, reverse is very expensive operation for what you need.

Comment: Thanks. Do I have to iterate through all rows in order to find the leftmost `True` pixel?

Comment: What can I do to find the top-most and bottom-most pixel with `True`?

Comment: @Dawn17 I added a new answer which results in all your requested values.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you? not most efficient, but works.
the idea is to remove rows and columns that's all False, so you get your 'cropped' digit.

```
import pandas as pd

img = np.array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
         True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
         True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        False]])

img = pd.DataFrame(img)
img.replace(False,np.nan, inplace = True)
newimage = img.dropna(axis = 0, how = 'all')
newimage = newimage.dropna(axis = 1, how = 'all')
newimage.T.values
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but for some reason, the black and white are flipped in the cropped image.

Comment: oh.. do newimage.T.values

Answer (score 0):

```
array = [[False, False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False],
         [True , False, False, False],
         [False, False, False, False]]

print('left: ')
print(min([x.index(True) if True in x else 100 for x in array]))

print('right: ')
print(min([x[::-1].index(True) if True in x else 100 for x in array]))

print('top')
print([any(x) for x in array].index(True))

print('bottom')    
print([any(x) for x in array[::-1]].index(True))
```

prints

```
left: 
0
right: 
3
top
2
bottom
1
```

Side notes:

- I used 100 for left/right in case there is no True at all in a row.
- If there is a chance for no True value at all in the entire matrix, conditions for top and bottom have to be changed slightly.
- ::-1 iterates the list in reverse order
- `any` checks for the occurrence of a non 0/empty/False value.
- `min` checks for the minimum value of a list
- [...] is called list comprehension in case you want to find more about it

With your values I get:

```
left:
14
right:
8
top:
4
bottom:
0
```